# Dagger Hilt cannot create an instance of ViewModel having a constructor with arguments

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

After going through documentations and trying solutions of similar questions here on stackoverflow, nothing seems to fix the issue.
I tried altering all related dependencies, trying additional dependencies and tweaking the versions. Gradle builds successfully but there is a runtime error that through trial and error, the only method I found that could fix it was removing the argument from the ViewModel which is not desirable for me as the same setup used to work in my older projects.

RuntimeException

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example, PID: 17527
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.ui.MainViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:188)
```

build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.6.10-1.0.2'
}

kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        debug {
            kotlin.srcDir("build/generated/ksp/debug/kotlin")
        }
        release {
            kotlin.srcDir("build/generated/ksp/release/kotlin")
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true

        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs += '-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha04'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"


    //lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.0"


    //Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"

    //Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0'

    //DataStore
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"

    //Desugaring
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'

    //Compose Destinations
    implementation "io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations:core:1.2.1-beta"
    ksp "io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations:ksp:1.2.1-beta"
```

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.0-alpha02'
        hilt_version = "2.40.5"
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0-beta01' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0-beta01' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

MainViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataStoreRepository: DataStoreRepository
) : ViewModel() {...}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DestinationsNavHost(navGraph = NavGraphs.root)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create module class? like below:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class RepositoryModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDataStoreRepository(): DataStoreRepository = DataStoreRepository()
}
```